# php file system functions don't work on remote server

Tags: php

on localhost (win7, xampp) this works fine:

```
$path = "NOTES\AA FILE - 323.txt";
$cnt = file_get_contents($path);
echo $cnt;  // content of the file
```

but on remote server - the same code - nothing is echoed

Also:

```
$old = "NOTES\A FOLDER";
$anew = "NOTES\PAY";
rename($old, $anew);
```

The above works on localhost and doesn't work on remote server (folder is not renamed)

Comment: Is your remote server also running Windows? Are you getting ANY output or error message after the rename call?

Comment: I hope file permissions are ok and the user from which this gets executed has the privileges.

Comment: @Nikster2014 afaik remote servers are all on linux. and no - there is no any error message

Comment: One difference between Windows and linux is that linux is case sensitive in file/directory names, so just check they are exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your remote server is running Linux, your paths should contain forward slashes, not back slashes! Try this:

```
    $old = "NOTES/A FOLDER";
$anew = "NOTES/PAY";
rename($old, $anew);
```

Comment: This should work for OP. As a better practice, we can use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` constant to properly get the path slashes for any OS environment.

Comment: "notes/a folder" doesn't look like a correct path name. Does the dir name really contain a space? Also, are your dir permissions set correctly? Try running the script as SU and see if that works

Comment: yes, spaces are there. those are folder names and I need spaces

Comment: In that case try to escape the spaces in the dir name: $old = "NOTES/A\ FOLDER";

Comment: now I replace all spaces with `_` - the same result

Comment: Did you actually change the dir names (spaces to underscores) or just replaces the spaces in the path with an underscore?

Comment: I did both - folders and files rename - and so adjust the paths

Comment: @qadenza Could be a permissions issue. Is PHP error logging switched on in the remote server? Check the log file for error messages. If it's not on, turn it on and try again.